# How to send PDF blob to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, blob

I've generated a PDF report using JSRepoprts library. The output result is a blob that can be downloaded to the "Downloads" folder. What I need to do is to save the blob in a specific folder on the server. I tried to send the blob using XMLHttpRequest, but I'm receiving the request with empty content in the controller.

The code I wrote is the following

```
jsreports.export({
        format: 'pdf',
        report_def: def,
        datasets: data_sources,
        outputHandler: function (pdfBlob) {
            $('.report-output-pdf').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob));

             var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhr.open('GET', '/reports/saveReport', true);

             xhr.onload = function () {       
                 console.log(xhr.responseText);
             };              
             xhr.send(pdfBlob);
        }
    });
```

On the server side (MVC Controller) the code is:

```
public ActionResult saveReport()
    {
        try
        {
            var r = Request;
            int l = Request.ContentLength; // Received 0
            byte[] ba = r.BinaryRead(r.ContentLength);

            return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

[Result as shown in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh9iI.png)

Any one have an idea that help me saving the pdf blob to specific directory using the correction of the code above or any other idea?

Comment: What is the type of `pdfBlob`? To use `send`, your `pdfBlob` must have `Blob` type with specified MIME type, otherwise it doesn't recognized as BLOB HTTP request. Have you tried something like `var blob = new Blob(pdfBlob, {type: 'application/pdf'});` before?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I'm still getting it with empty content. I'll edit my post to show you what's being shown in debugger @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Are you sure that the file is actually being sent by the browser? What does the devtools show. Furthermore this is not the recommended way to read a file form a request I would add a IFormFile parameter to the controller method

Comment: The developers tool showed an error [[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)]] on the return statement and the printed message in the console is [[circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule]]. Would you please post the recommended way to read a file from request?? if you have an alternative solution please let me see it @GeorgiGeorgiev